# View/test Amazon Mechanical Turk qualification published to sandbox

Tags: mechanicalturk

What is the proper way of publishing and then testing a qualification test in the amazon mechanical turk sandbox?

I'm trying to test out a qualification test in the sandbox by viewing/taking it as a sandbox worker, however, when I go to the given URL, the page says "Sorry, we couldn't find that page."

I'm using the [command line tools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkCLT/CLTReference_CreateQualificationTypeCommand.html). I create the test like this:

```
./createQualificationType.sh -sandbox -properties test.properties -question test.question
```

Which completes successfully and prints:

```
Sandbox override
Created qualification type: 33RG09AB3LBTH7EBTMTWQEKYEKOTQA
You can take the test here: https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/requestqualification?qualificationId=33RG09AB3LBTH7EBTMTWQEKYEKOTQA
```

where the long string is the qualification type's ID. However, when I try to access the URL, I get a page that says

```
Sorry, we couldn’t find that page
Strange... the page you were looking for is not here. Let’s go home and try again.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the test link working. To try out the test, I attached the qualification type to a sandbox HIT and then went to the HIT as a sandbox worker.